# Multiple TagSet nodes not working in aws cli

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags, aws-cli

As per [aws cli put-bucket-tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-tagging.html) doc, I am able to execute following command

```
aws s3api put-bucket-tagging --bucket my-bucket --tagging file://tagging.json
```

with **tagging.json** file (case 1)

```
{
   "TagSet": [
     {
       "Key": "organization",
       "Value": "marketing"
     }
   ]
}
```

Suppose my **tagging.json** file contains multiple **TagSet** nodes like (case 2)

```
{  
   "TagSet":[  
      {  
         "Key":"organization",
         "Value":"marketing"
      }
   ],
   "TagSet":[  
      {  
         "Key":"test",
         "Value":"market"
      }
   ]
}
```

In this case, aws cli parses only first **TagSet** node which is similar to that of **case 1**. So the question is

1. How can I parse multiple **TagSet** nodes or test such requests with s3.
2. What is s3 behaviour if there are multiple **TagSet** nodes in request body. Something like

```xml
<Tagging>
  <TagSet>
     <Tag>
       <Key>Tag Name</Key>
       <Value>Tag Value</Value>
     </Tag>
  </TagSet>
  <TagSet>
     <Tag>
       <Key>Tag Name2</Key>
       <Value>Tag Value2</Value>
     </Tag>
  </TagSet>
</Tagging>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about multiple TagSet nodes, I think the syntax of the file will need to be like so:

```
{  
   "TagSet":[  
      {  
         "Key":"organization",
         "Value":"marketing"
      },
      {  
         "Key":"test",
         "Value":"market"
      }
   ]
}
```

TagSet will require to be a Single Key that contains a list of Key/Value tags so that AWS can parse them correctly, having multiple TagSet key's in the JSON Structure looks like AWS accepts the first one and drops anything after.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have clearly mentioned that I want to see s3 behaviour with more than one **TagSet** node & not multiple key-value pairs within **TagSet** node

Comment: You asked: 

How can I parse multiple TagSet nodes or test such requests with s3.
What is s3 behaviour if there are multiple TagSet nodes in request body. Something like

I'm mentioning that I think what you are trying to achieve is not possible, if you look at the documentation it explicitly shows structure like so: `TagSet=[{Key=string,Value=string},{Key=string,Value=string}]` which seems like the only valid option.  If you wish to try "two" TagSet nodes then you can't do this natively with the CLI it seems.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way I can check how s3 behaves if I include multiple TagSet nodes??

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself running the CLI command with a file like that and find out? I don't understand what the problem is there... you haven't clarified.

Comment: aws cli is ignoring second **TagSet** node so I wanted to see if I forcefully include that node how aws s3 would behave I have also mentioned cases I have executed.